# How to set child width equal to parent element width with css?

Tags: css

My html is:

```
.parent
  .child
```

and the .parent width is not determined value, .child width is 100%, both child and parent has own border, at last the child element width is less 2px then parent's width,

How can I set the child width equal to parent element width only with css?

Comment: post your code will help you lot

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the child element is `display: block;` (many elements are by default) and don't set any width for it. Block elements take up all the horizontal space they can get by default.

Comment: What is it then? Why not set it to block?

Comment: I just set the child element display to block, but it didn't work, I am searching problem

Comment: Then you'll need to post some code. How about a code snippet or jsfiddle that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it. I remove border from .parent and add border to .child sibling element, then it works

Comment: html structure `.parent > .sibling + .child `

Answer (score 0):

Set the padding to 0 in the parent. So in the parent css class add `padding: 0px;` this should fix it. You may also need to set `margin: 0px;` in the child css class. Also try `display: block;`.